# Quando usar a declaração !important

Tags: css, wordpress-theme

Estou criando um site no Wordpress, e o tema definia a cor da fonte para todas as páginas. Queria alterar a cor da fonte numa textarea dos comentários do blog. Criei um tema filho e na página de estilo alterei a cor usando a propriedade "color". Atualizei o site, mas a alteração não fez efeito. Pesquisando na web descobri a utilização da declaração !important. Implementei e deu certo. Foi correto o que fiz?

Comment: Não é o ideal. O correto seria funcionar em cascata, como o próprio nome a define. Recomendo esse artigo para saber mais: https://zenorocha.com/css-important/

Comment: Entendo. É que a propriedade foi feita inline no HTML da página. Achei que colocando na folha de estilo externa (filho) estaria correto, numa futura atualização do tema pai. Mas obrigado.

Comment: O !important basicamente diz para o browser ignorar a hierarquia do CSS e usar o estilo que estiver usando !important. Não existe muito certo e errado se tratando de um Framework do tamanho do WP, lógico que o melhor seria não usalo, mas como nem sempre o CSS está disponível vai assim mesmo, Não se preocupe quanto a isso, a não ser que vc vá colocar !important em todas as classes